# How to find object in array by property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Exist an array with a lot of objects. Required to find an object or objects in this array by property.

Input obj:

```
  var Obj = [
    {"start": 0, "length": 3, "style": "text"},
    {"start": 4, "length": 2, "style": "operator"},
    {"start": 4, "length": 3, "style": "error"}
  ];
```

Output result: (search for "start" with value 4)

```
  var result = [
    {"start": 4, "length": 2, "style": "operator"},
    {"start": 4, "length": 3, "style": "error"}
  ];
```

Comment: Less than a minute to resolve your own problem! Amazing.

Comment: (Stop drinking wared, you see double...)

Comment: @wared What's wrong? This is just small tip in Q&A style.

Comment: Problem is that it's a common and fairly trivial problem. Did you verify that there are no duplicates?

Comment: @BlueSkies I've found dups, but there top solutions are terrible.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what some terrible solutions look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_findItemByValue(Obj, "start", 4);

```
var _findItemByValue = function(obj, prop, value) {
  return obj.filter(function(item) {
    return (item[prop] === value);
  });
}
```

Compatible with all except IE6, IE7, IE8, but exist [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function (fn, context) {
    var i,
        value,
        result = [],
        length;

        if (!this || typeof fn !== 'function' || (fn instanceof RegExp)) {
          throw new TypeError();
        }

        length = this.length;

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            value = this[i];
            if (fn.call(context, value, i, this)) {
              result.push(value);
            }
          }
        }
    return result;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function of array

```js
var Obj = [
  {"start": 0, "length": 3, "style": "text"},
  {"start": 4, "length": 2, "style": "operator"},
  {"start": 4, "length": 3, "style": "error"}
];

var result = Obj.filter(x => x.start === 4);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create an util function like below which works for filtering the array based on any key using the filter method of Array.

```
function filterObjects(objArr,key,value){      
      return objArr.filter(obj => obj[key]===value);    
}
    
filterObjects(objArr,'name','Email');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply