# JavaScript : searching an array and returning value after user input

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var data = [{
  id: 'A1',
  name: 'Minstrels'
}, {
  id: 'A2',
  name: 'Bounty'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Crunchie'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'bar'
}];

var rl = require('readline')

var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

prompts.question('Which Product do you want to purchase? ',
  function(Answer1) {
    //missing code goes here in order to return Minstrels if the user 
    //types 'A1' etc..
  }
)
```

I need help in my code. I have enabled user input and made an array, however, I can't think of what my code is missing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yeah i pasted the wrong code into the box, the 'food:' wasn't supposed to be there

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) array method to locate the first element matching the given predicate, then additionally handles the case where the item was not located.  Because your example uses both strings and numbers for `id` values, we explicitly coerce each object's `id` to a string during comparison to simplify the strict comparison:

```
var item = data.find(i => ("" + i.id) === Answer1);

console.log(item ? item.name : 'No such food');
```