# Log matching objects in Console

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I'm working with JavaScript objects where if the ID of a person is found in a team array, log the matches in console.

```
var employees = {
  "team1": [3,0],
  "team2": [1,2],
  "people": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John",
    "description": "test test test",
    "img": ""
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adam",
    "description": "this is a test",
    "img": ""
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Fred",
    "description": "fjdk;sf;lsd,;fl,s;l",
    "img": ""
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bill Murray",
    "description": "fndsjlfnlskdm",
    "img": ""
  }
}]
};
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I know that its kind of a vague question but I'm afraid, I'm getting sucked down the vortex that can be Google and I think I'm making it more difficult for myself than it needs to be. If anyone has any suggestions on how to accomplish this, I'd love some help going in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: google would probably be much less of a vortex if you use the proper terminology.. it's a javascript object, not a json object.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? The title says "Sort", but the question just says to log matches.

Comment: You might find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: @Tanckom Despite the title, his question doesn't seem to be about sorting.

Comment: Just seen that he changed title. I guess this is then done with an forEach and indexOf in that case

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're correct. Apologies for the confusion. Still learning terminology. But essentially if a person matches a team, log that persons info to the console.

Comment: There's just one object here. What array are you searching?

Comment: @Barmar I think he refers to `employee.people`

Comment: @Ander2 But he says to search the team array, which sounds like `emploee.team1` and `employee.team2`.

Comment: Could you give an example of input and the desired output?

Comment: @Barmar Didn't mean to cause any confusion. If a person matches a team, log the team of people.

Comment: What does that mean? Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @barmar essentially exactly the answer provided below, perhaps just minus the arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var employees = {
  "team1": [3, 0],
  "team2": [1, 2],
  "people": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "John",
      "description": "test test test",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Adam",
      "description": "this is a test",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fred",
      "description": "fjdk;sf;lsd,;fl,s;l",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Bill Murray",
      "description": "fndsjlfnlskdm",
      "img": ""
    }]
};


var id = 3;
var person = employees.people.filter(function(row){return row.id == id})[0] || "No one by that ID";
console.log(person)
```

---

Bonus option (Just for fun): using [Javascript Query Language](http://pamblam.github.io/jSQL/)

```js
var employees = {
  "team1": [3, 0],
  "team2": [1, 2],
  "people": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "John",
      "description": "test test test",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Adam",
      "description": "this is a test",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fred",
      "description": "fjdk;sf;lsd,;fl,s;l",
      "img": ""
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Bill Murray",
      "description": "fndsjlfnlskdm",
      "img": ""
    }]
};

var id = 3;
jSQL.createTable("employees", employees.people).execute();
var person = jSQL.query("select * from employees where id = ?").execute([id]).fetch("ASSOC");
console.log(person);
```

```html
<script src="https://pamblam.github.io/jSQL/scripts/jSQL.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suspect this isn't what he's asking about. And if it is, you could just close as a dupe ofhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript

Comment: Would you possibly be able to revise that last line without arrow functions?

Comment: @thelgloriouspast The answers in the duplicate show how to do it in many different ways.

Comment: @thelgloriouspast - Ok, sure thing