# Can access JSON attributes from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

my json:

```
     {
  locale: "en",
  title: "Survey",
  focusFirstQuestionAutomatic: false,
  pages: [
   {
    name: "livingEnvironment",
    elements: [
     {
      type: "html",
      name: "navigationWarning",
      html: "To navigate "
     },
     {
      type: "html",
      name: "IntroEnvironment",
      html: "We will now ask you questions about your living environment"
     },
     {
      type: "text",
      name: "numhousehold",
      width: "auto",
      title: "How many people (including yourself) lived in your household",
      validators: [
       {
        type: "numeric",
        text: "Please enter a number between 1 and 99.",
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 99
       }
      ],
      inputType: "number"
     },
     {
      type: "multipletext",
      name: "householdtype",
      width: "auto",
      title: "Of these, how many (including yourself) were:",
      items: [
       {
        name: "children",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Children under 18 years old",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        name: "adults",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Adults between 18-59 years old",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        name: "seniors",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Seniors (60+)",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        name: "disabled",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Disabled",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]

      }
   }
 ]}
```

and my javascript is:

```
function serverValidateQuestion(survey, options) {
            console.log('Validation called');
            console.log(options.data.householdtype);
            console.log(options.data.householdtype.children);
```

so i can access `console.log(options.data.householdtype)` and it gives me the list of items in the in household type. However i am trying to access the "children" value input from householdtype. and when i write console.log(options.data.householdtype.children) it gives me

```
`
```

> Cannot read property of undefined” error. On google console mode,
>   "console.log(options.data.householdtype)" gives me this :

` "adults
    :
    "3"
    children
    :
    "3"
    disabled
    :
    "3"
    pregnant
    :
    "3"
    seniors
    :
    "3"
    **proto**
    :
    Object

but i only want to access the children value and `console.log(options.data.householdtype.children)` doesn't work. Additionally, `console.log(options.data.numhousehold)` does give me a value that the user inputted. Also, these value are from an input box that users fill-out during a survey. Help me please.

Comment: I don't see a `householdtype` property anywhere in the JSON. I see `name: "householdtype"` and `name: "children"`, but those are values, not property names.

Comment: the json does not have matching braces

Comment: This can't be the object you're referencing when you use `options.data.householdtype`.

Comment: Please edit and format your post, this is unreadable.

Comment: @Barmar I mean accessing the value name:"children"

Comment: @ChrisR Which part is unreadable?

Comment: @Barmar I just want to know how to access the name:" children" via javascript

Comment: @jackMak can you put whole json output? There is no householdtype in that example above. Try to give us more code. How do you call that function "serverValidateQuestion"? what is 'survey' and what is 'options'? I guess the survey is that json that you have shown?

Comment: @jackMak You can't access properties by value directly. You have to loop over all the objects in the `pages.elements` array until you find the one with `name = "householdtype"`. Then you loop over that one's `items` array until you find `name = "children"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

ok so i figured it out It is because the on the first page of my html file  console.log(options.data.householdtype); gives undefined. On second page of my html does it locate the householdtype then it is able to access console.log(options.data.householdtype.children); otherwise it doesn't work.