# Adding Points when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, click

I have this html code

```
<button onclick="Jason()">Jason</button>
<button onclick="Mark()">Mark</button>
<button onclick="Lucas()">Lucas</button>
```

with this script

```
const persons = [
        {Name: Jason, Points: 0},
        {Name: Mark, Points: 0},
        {Name: Lucas, Points: 0},
];
```

I want to know how to use a function to add points to the corresponding persons on each button each time I click on it.

and is there any way to display the score in real time? (not necessary but would love to know how to do it)

Comment: What do you mean by `real time`?

Comment: That's more of a data structure. Where's your code attempt? ... Also, do you plan to name all of your functions after person's name? Not a good strategy -- not reusable.

Comment: Don't use a separate function for each person. Write a single function that takes the person name as a parameter. Then you can find the matching object in the array, and increment its `Points` property.

Comment: `onclick="AddPoint('Jason')"`

Comment: You display the score in real time by updating the score DIV's `textContent` with the new score.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript for how to find the object with a particular name.

Comment: @Tân like when you press the button of a person it displays the point added to that person in the html page

Comment: @GetSet I don't know much about JS, i tried and looked for different things but none of them worked for what i need, and no, i used those names just as examples, each item will be unique