# Getting JSON value from key, where key is variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to get the value of a key in a JSON object, and the name of the key is in a variable.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var id = 230345038039;
var jsonstuff = 
var parsedstuff = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./file.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(parsedstuff.id);
```

Expected output: 12

I've tried `parsedstuff.$$id`, `parsedstuff.${!id}` and `parsedstuff.$id`. None work.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: SOLVED. parsedstuff[id] is what I should be using.

Comment: `parsedstuff[id]`

Comment: @lastr2d2 Still returns undefined.

Comment: Then there's nothing with that key. Maybe you're looking for an element with `id: 230345038039`?

Comment: Post an example of the JSON and the desired result.

Comment: If that's what you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript