# How to get an element inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this array which is named `options_hotel`, it has 2 arrays (but can have more depending on how many registries are fetched from DB)

both arrays have elements inside, such as `ID`, `NOM` & `ADRESSE` :

```
 Array(2)
0: {ID: "1", NOM: "Le messager", ADRESSE: "30 rue du messager"}
1: {ID: "2", NOM: "hydrargyre", ADRESSE: "12 avenue hydrargyre"}
```

I have a `select` where options will be created dynamically,

```
<h2 class="list-titre">Hôtels</h2>
<select id="new_hotel"><!-- --></select>
```

Those options are created dynamically with javascript (& JQUERY), by getting `NOM` & `ID` from each hotel.

```
for(i=0; i<options_hotel.length; i++){
    $("#new_hotel").append(new Option(options_hotel[i]['NOM'],options_hotel[i]['ID'] ));
}
```

Finally I have an input for adresses:

```
<h2 class="list-titre">Adresse</h2>
<input id="new_adresse" type="text" name="new_adresse" required>
```

So i want `#new_adresse` element to have the value of `ADRESSE` (which is stored in `options_hotel`)   corresponding to the value of `#new_hotel`.

**For instance** : if the value inside `#new_hotel` is `1` (and the text is `Le messager`), then i want inside `#new_adresse` : `30 rue du messager`.

Thank you

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Getting the selecte value of the dropdown? Searching for that in the `ID` properties of the array? Copying the `ADRESSE` property to `#new_adresse`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript for finding an object by property value

Comment: @Barmar its copying the ```ADRESS``` property to ```#new_adresse``` which is the problem

Comment: `$("#new_adresse").val(obj.ADRESSE)` where `obj` is the found object.

Answer (score 1):

I actually transformed your original array into an object (using `.reduce()`), as this will make it easier to find the corresponding sub-object with the `.ADRESSE` attribute.

I also took the liberty of slightly rewriting your select-filling part and combining it with the `change`-event handling function. The repeated `.append()` operation is replaced by a single `.html()` call that applies some prepared HTML code to the select element. In this little example it will not make the slightest difference, but, generally speaking, repeated `.append()` operations *can* slow down the user experience, as each one of them requires a rebuild of the DOM in the browser.

```js
const options_hotel=[
 {ID: "1", NOM: "Le messager", ADRESSE: "30 rue du messager"},
 {ID: "2", NOM: "hydrargyre", ADRESSE: "12 avenue hydrargyre"},
 {ID: "5", NOM: "The Four Seasons", ADRESSE: "5 avenue du président"}]
 .reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.ID]=c,a),{} );
 
 const options3=[
 {ID: "8", NOM: "Le foudroyant", ADRESSE: "76 rue de Zeus"},
 {ID: "9", NOM: "Leclair", ADRESSE: "23 rue de Zeus"},
 {ID: "14", NOM: "The Five Seasons", ADRESSE: "15 avenue de la nation"}] 
 .reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.ID]=c,a),{} );

$.fn.hotelAdresse=function(opts,inpSel){ // made a plugin to avoid repetition ...
 this  // this is the jQuery element referencing a single <select> element
  .html(Object.values(opts).map(h=>new Option(h.NOM,h.ID).outerHTML).join(""))
  .change(function(){$(inpSel).val(opts[this.value].ADRESSE)})
  .change();  // show the ADRESSE for the initially chosen option ...
}
$("#new_hotel").hotelAdresse(options_hotel,"#new_adresse");
$("#newer_hotel").hotelAdresse(options_hotel,"#newer_adresse");
$("#hotel3").hotelAdresse(options3,"#adresse3");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="list-titre">Hôtels 1</h2>
<select id="new_hotel"></select> Adresse 
<input id="new_adresse" type="text" name="new_adresse" required>
<h2 class="list-titre">Hôtels 2 (same data as Hôtels 1)</h2>
<select id="newer_hotel"></select> Adresse 
<input id="newer_adresse" type="text" name="newer_adresse" required>
<h2 class="list-titre">Hôtels 3 (different data object)</h2>
<select id="hotel3"></select> Adresse 
<input id="adresse3" type="text" name="adresse3" required>
```

Instead of applying the `.reduce()` function to an array you can of course start out with an object like

```
options_hotel=
{
  "1": {
    "ID": "1",
    "NOM": "Le messager",
    "ADRESSE": "30 rue du messager"
  },
  "2": {
    "ID": "2",
    "NOM": "hydrargyre",
    "ADRESSE": "12 avenue hydrargyre"
  },
  "5": {
    "ID": "5",
    "NOM": "The Four Seasons",
    "ADRESSE": "5 avenue du président"
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, but i don't understand what is happening, for instance why are you applying ```.reduce``` to the array?

Comment: With `.reduce` I create an object (or "hash") in which I can directly search a particular sub-object with a key (`ID`) . In my example code I added another select element with ID=5. This can be found directly in the object without having to loop through it. The lookup happens in the change function: `options_hotel[this.value].ADRESSE`.

Comment: However, this does not work if i have multiple ```options_hotel``` containing different values in them (```Script.js:162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ADRESSE' of undefined```. Because whenever i change the ```options_hotel``` the reduce works but the text inside ```#new_adresse``` does not change

Comment: Could you add the case to your question please? I have not yet understood exactly whether you are talking about multiple select elements or multiple options_hotel objects and in which situation exactly you encounter the error you wrote about.

Comment: Yes it's about muliple ```options_hotel``` for instance : ```Array(2)
0: {ID: "8", NOM: "Le foudroyant", ADRESSE: "76 rue de Zeus"}
1: {ID: "9", NOM: "Leclair", ADRESSE: "23 rue de Zeus"}```

Comment: I extended my snippet and added both some more selects and another name/address object. Check it out.