# How to log only matched condition using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of object, which is dynamic, I want to log variation price conditionally, For example, if variations contains `paper` i want to display **only paper price and not ebook and audio price**, On the other hand if variation'll not contains `paper` i want to log `ebook` **price only**
same logic with `audio`, I have just started learning JavaScript and I'm a little confused,
All advice will be acceptable to me, Thanks!

```js
variations: [
  {
    variation:'paper',
    price:'44'
  },
  {
    variation:'ebook',
    price:'41'
  },
  {
    variation:'audio',
    price:'40'
  }
],
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop that looks for each variation in order. When it finds one, it displays the price, then breaks out of the loop.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your priority is to log `paper`, and if it doesn't exist log the `ebook` price, and if this doesn't exist as well, log the `audio` price?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript for how to find the array element with the `variation` you want.

Comment: @RonB Yes, exactly

Comment: learn about `find()`

Comment: could there be more than one entry of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trick you can do:

First, you can convert the array you have to a more suiting data structure. You can turn it into an object with the `variation` as key and the `price` as value.

Do it like so:

```
const variationPrices = {};
variations.forEach( v => variationPrices[v.variation] = v.price)
```

After that, in your example, `variationPrices` will look like that:

```
{
    paper: 44,
    ebook: 41,
    audio: 40
}
```

Afterwards, you can log by your priority like that:

```
console.log(variationPrices.paper || variationPrices.ebook || variationPrices.audio)
```

What the `||` operator does in this case is like saying "if that thing doesn't exist, choose the one after it", so if `variationPrices.paper` is `undefined`, it will try to get `variationPrices.ebook` and so on