# Javascript - Retrieve the value of an object based on the ID of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects 'assignmentResults' as follows:

```
[
    {'id':'1','skillIds':[1, 2]},
    {'id':'2','skillIds':[2,3]}
```

And I also have an array of skills:

```
[
    {'id':'1','name':skill1},
    {'id':'2','name':'skill2', 
    {'id':'3','name':'skill3'}
```

With this information I would like to return the `skillIds` from `assignmentResults` as a name from the skills. For example if the value of `skillIds` (from `assignmentResults`) is `[1,2]`, It'll return `'skill1'` and `'skill2'`. I tried to experiment with various JS array functions using `.map`, `.filter` and `.find`, but I haven't been able to achieve this result. I'm using vue JS to achieve this which through the following computed properties I'm retrieving the data mentioned above:

```
const searchResults = computed(() => {
    return store.getters.getSearchResults
});

const skillList = computed(() => { 
   return root.$store.getters.getSkills 
});
```

I have been going at it for a while and I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is it an array of skills instead of an object, so you can easily get the skill name from the skill ID?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy.

```js
var data =[
    {'id':'1','name':"skill1"},
    {'id':'2','name':'skill2'}, 
    {'id':'3','name':'skill3'} 
]

const getSkills =(ids)=>{
  return data.filter(x=> ids.includes(parseInt(x.id))).map(x=> x.name);
}


console.log(getSkills([1,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```js
const assignmentResults = [
    {'id':'1','skillIds':['1','2']},
    {'id':'2','skillIds':['2','3']}
];
const skills = [
    {'id':'1','name':'skill1'},
    {'id':'2','name':'skill2'}, 
    {'id':'3','name':'skill3'} 
];

const skillsForAssignment = (assignment) => assignmentResults
  .find(ar => ar.id === assignment).skillIds
    .map(sid => skills.find(sk => sk.id === sid).name);
    
console.log(skillsForAssignment("1"));
console.log(skillsForAssignment("2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//example assignments
const assignments = [
    {'id':'1','skillIds':[1, 2]},
    {'id':'2','skillIds':[2,3]},
    {'id':'4','skillIds':[4,5]}
];
//example skills
const skills = [
    {'id':'1','name':'skill1'},
    {'id':'2','name':'skill2'}, 
    {'id':'3','name':'skill3'} 
];

//function gets the skill names from the assignments at the selected assignments id
function getSkillNames(reqId, assignments, skills){
   const skillids = assignments.filter((a) => a.id === reqId.toString()).map((b) => b.skillIds)[0];
   //if skillids are not undefined, do a search of skills, if found return
   //names else empty array
   if(skillids !== undefined)
    return skills.filter((a) => skillids.includes(parseInt(a.id))).map((b) => b.name) || [];
   else //return empty array
    return [];
}

console.log(getSkillNames(1, assignments, skills));
console.log(getSkillNames(4, assignments, skills));
```