Updating a value in String.raw block via REGEXP or something else?
I'm printing some values inside my HTML page where a textarea carries values that are String.raw. For example:
<script>

var ENV = String.raw`
{
    "id": "15bbb91c-b9d9-4238-8eb5-01c991d613ba",
    "name": ""${ENV_NAME_VARIABLE}"
}
`;

document.write(`
   <textarea id="envid" >` + ENV + ` </textarea>
`
);
</script>

This textarea shows up properly. Now through some interactivity in the page, let's say a button, I want to change the value of this ENV_NAME_VARIABLE, and I'd like to show that in the textarea in the page. How could I retrieve the current value inside this bit, and replace with a new value?
<script>

    let ENV_NAME_VARIABLE = 'TESTING NAME';

    var ENV = String.raw`
    {
        "id": "15bbb91c-b9d9-4238-8eb5-01c991d613ba",
        "name": "${ENV_NAME_VARIABLE}""
    }
    `;

    document.write(`
    <textarea id="ENV" style="width: 80%; height: 100">` + ENV + ` </textarea>
    `
    );


    function updateName() { 
        original_text = document.getElementById('ENV').value;
        //////------ HERE I WANT TO GET THE value of ENV_NAME_VARIABLE..... 
        /////--------- AND REPLACE THAT to ABC
    }

</script>

<p>
<button onclick="updateName(); ">Change value of name to ABC</button>


Use JSON.parse() to parse the contents of the textarea, replace the name property, then convert it back to JSON.
BTW, I recommend you use JSON.stringify() to create the textarea in the first place, rather than substituting in a template literal.


let ENV_NAME_VARIABLE = 'TESTING NAME';

var ENV = String.raw `
    {
        "id": "15bbb91c-b9d9-4238-8eb5-01c991d613ba",
        "name": "${ENV_NAME_VARIABLE}"
    }
    `;

document.write(`
    <textarea id="ENV" style="width: 80%; height: 100">` + ENV + ` </textarea>
    `);


function updateName() {
  let obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ENV').value);
  obj.name = 'ABC';
  document.getElementById('ENV').value = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
}
<button onclick="updateName(); ">Change value of name to ABC</button>




Thank you for this. Looks like what I will need. The JSON block I shared as sample has many values[] and there are multiple id and name values inside. How would I target the name where the id is 15bbb91c-b9d9-4238-8eb5-01c991d613ba for example?

If you have an array of objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195958/how-to-find-object-in-array-by-property-in-javascript
